# How do you change your email settings for all sites?

Tags: support, subscription

Is there a way to make settings apply to all sites for my login?

For example, if I go to settings for one site and uncheck the option

```
Email chat event reminders, bounty expiration notices, and achievement announcements
```

then check this setting on another site, the change doesn't propagate to the other site. Does it take time? Or do I have to do it on a per-site basis?

Comment: I think there isn't such a way, and it will be a good idea to add such an option. :)